# Max Current Limiter for Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, power, transistors

This is probably an easy question for many of you. I am newbie, so just asking this question.

I am creating a workbench power supply for my projects. I have not created the circuit myself. Instead used a ready-to-use 1.3v-32v 10 Amp DC-DC Buck Converter module. My transformer is 12-0-12 4 Amp rated. So, my buck converter always finds enough opportunity to remain cool :)

Unfortunately the buck converter module has 2 POTs to control the output voltage. But there is no built in Current Limiter. However I want to limit the max output current of the device.

I am trying to use the following circuit to achieve this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFuvry.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My questions are:
1. Will this circuit work?
2. Is the position of transistor based Current Controller unit correct? Or should it be placed between Bridge Rectifier and the Buck Converter module?
3. Is 1 Watt POT safe to use at transistor base to control current (max allowed upto 4Amp).

Comment: 1. The circuit will not work. It is hard to answer what you have simply. To have a wide range of current limit, doing with just transistors would be complicated. My approach would most likely be to reduce power supply output by injecting current (i.e. raise the voltage) at the wiper node of 10K pot. That would probably be driven by some opamp circuit that senses the output current. The position you have is good because it does not mess with ground, but the sensing would need to be done at up to 32V. Alternatively, low side sensing would be easier, but then it messes with ground.

Comment: If the sensing needs to be done at higher voltage, can I just place the current limiter part between filter cap and the Buck Converter module? I mean, from the left the circuit should be - Trafo -> Bridge Rectifier -> Filter Capacitor -> Current Limiting Transistor (and biasing resistances) -> Buck Converter - >Output. It would, in that case, work at 24V atleast.

Comment: Placing a current limit at the buck converter input limits the power it gets, that does not translate a specific current limit on the output (and there are other complications).